HMR in a SvelteKit & Vite project using Docker & Docker Compose
I am trying to get HMR working with my SvelteKit project using Docker and Docker Compose, but i just cant figure it out. I have been looking up several sources, and all look very similar, but have each their slight differences. My main source of inspiration is this Youtube video.
As of now, i can get my project to run, but when i change files, the container is not being updated. My database works well, it runs and i get access to it in the container when my application is developed by the simple "npm run dev". i have not yet tried to access the database when both database and application is containerized.
./application/Dockerfile:
FROM node:21-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5173

CMD ["npm", "run", "host"]

./application/vite.config.ts :
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
});

./docker-compose.yaml :
version: '3.8'

services:
  surrealdb:
    image: surrealdb/surrealdb:latest
    env_file:
      - .env
    entrypoint: 
      - /surreal
      - start
      - --user
      - $DATABASE_USER
      - --pass
      - $DATABASE_PASS
      - file:data
    volumes: 
      - $DATABASE_LOCATION:/data
    ports:
      - $DATABASE_PORT:8000
    extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

  sveltekit:
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: ./application
    ports:
      - 5173:5173
    volumes:
      - ./application:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules/

./.env :

# Raspberry PI IP Address.
IP_ADDRESS=192.168.1.20
DATABASE_PORT=3456

# Wifi credentials.
WIFI_SSID=my-ssid
WIFI_PASSWORD=my-password

# Database credentials.
DATABASE_USER=admin_username
DATABASE_PASS=some_secret_password

# Database location on disk.
DATABASE_LOCATION=./database/data

# Database namespace and database.
SURREAL_NS=root
SURREAL_DB=root

# Others
# SURREAL_PATH=file:data
SURREAL_CAPS_ALLOW_SCRIPT=true
SURREAL_AUTH=true

How do i get HMR working from this standpoint?

I'd run the Node application directly on the host for live development.  Since the database has published ports:, you should be able to configure the application to use the database in the container.

This is how I got HMR to work in a dockerized SvelteKit app running in dev mode (the following assumes the docker configuration files are located at the root of your SvelteKit project, amend paths if otherwise):
# ./Dockerfile

# Use the alpine version that suits your needs, based
# on the Node version you want to use. If possible use
# the latest stable version (recommended for a newly
# created SvelteKit project).
FROM node:alpine

# Use whichever container directory you want as long
# as you make sure to use it consistently in further
# configuration. I'll just use '/app' here for simplicity.
WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

# Using the --host 0.0.0.0 option (which is passed to Vite)
# was the only way I could get the dev/HMR mode to be
# accessible from outside the container.
CMD npm run dev -- --host 0.0.0.0

Build and test with:
docker build -t docker-svelte-test:latest .
docker run -it -p 5173:5173 -v /app/node_modules -v .:/app docker-svelte-test:latest
The -it flag will let you interact with the server (restart, quit, etc.). The port mapping option is self-explanatory (note that I did not need to EXPOSE the port in the Dockerfile). The volume (-v) declarations are very important to get HMR to work, and need to be declared in that order. The first one persists /app/node_modules, which allows us to then map /app to our project's root directory without impacting node_modules. Because /app is mapped to the project's directory, changes made to the source files will be immediately reflected in the application running on the container (= HMR working).
Once you have tested that HMR is indeed working, putting together a corresponding docker-compose file is very straightforward:
# ./docker-compose.yml

services:
  dev:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 5173:5173
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app

And you can invoke it with docker compose up. Note that you no longer have the benefit of an interactive server (the -it flag we passed to docker run is no longer available). HMR should still be fully functional however.
Note that this is only valid as long as you do not install new modules with npm. If you do, you will have to rebuild your image and restart your container. But for HTML/CSS editing using HMR it works perfectly.
I have tested this using adpater-auto as well as adapter-static. In fact it should work with any adapters as these only come into play during the build phase and are thus irrelevant in the context of getting HMR to work in dev mode.
